# Transpor um dataframe no R

Tags: r, reshape

Possuo um dataframe no R, as colunas possuem datas e valores e as linhas possuem os países.

```
 LOCATION jan 1999 fev 1999  mar 1999
 EU28     86.70000 85.50000  85.90000
 JPN      99.76086 99.76086  101.47350
 USA      90.87153 91.62469  91.56094
```

Tentei transpor usando a função `t`, porém, ela transforma o dataframe em matriz, e gostaria que continuasse como dataframe, porém, da seguinte forma:

```
    Data      EU28  JPN        USA
    jan 1999  86.7  99.76086   90.87153
    fev 1999  85.5  99.76086   91.62469
    mar 1999  85.9  101.47350  91.56094
```

Função que utilizei: `df <- t(df)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode-se fazer o que a pergunta pede com o `xtabs` depois de reformatar os dados de formato largo para formato longo.
Nesta solução `row.names(df2)` dá as datas.

```
df2 <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = 'LOCATION')
df2 <- xtabs(value ~ variable + LOCATION, df2)
df2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(df2)
#         EU28       JPN      USA
#jan.1999 86.7  99.76086 90.87153
#fev.1999 85.5  99.76086 91.62469
#mar.1999 85.9 101.47350 91.56094
```

Para ter uma coluna com as datas poderá ser

```
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(Data = row.names(df2), df2)
row.names(df2) <- NULL
df2
#      Data EU28       JPN      USA
#1 jan.1999 86.7  99.76086 90.87153
#2 fev.1999 85.5  99.76086 91.62469
#3 mar.1999 85.9 101.47350 91.56094
```

Outro modo é com o pacote `dplyr`. Na solução abaixo a primeira coluna é a coluna de datas.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(variable, value, -LOCATION) %>%
  xtabs(formula = value ~ variable + LOCATION, data = .) %>%
  as.data.frame.matrix() %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "Data")
#      Data EU28       JPN      USA
#1 fev.1999 85.5  99.76086 91.62469
#2 jan.1999 86.7  99.76086 90.87153
#3 mar.1999 85.9 101.47350 91.56094
```

**Dados.**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
LOCATION 'jan 1999' 'fev 1999'  'mar 1999'
 EU28     86.70000 85.50000  85.90000
 JPN      99.76086 99.76086  101.47350
 USA      90.87153 91.62469  91.56094
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela solução!

Answer (score 5):

Basta fazer:

```
as.data.frame(t(df))
```

EDIT: como disse no comentário, talvez seja melhor usar '_' em vez de espaço no nome das variáveis. Nesse caso, temos:

```
> df
    LOCATION jan_1999 fev_1999  mar_1999
1  EU28      86.70000 85.50000  85.90000
2  JPN       99.76086 99.76086 101.47350
3  USA       90.87153 91.62469  91.56094
```

Após a aplicação da função:

```
> as.data.frame(t(df))
                 V1         V2         V3
LOCATION  EU28       JPN        USA      
jan_1999   86.70000   99.76086   90.87153
fev_1999   85.50000   99.76086   91.62469
mar_1999   85.90000  101.47350   91.56094
```

Note que será necessário apagar a primeira linha e renomear as colunas para alcançar o *output* desejado

Comment: Retorna o erro `Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`

Comment: Possivelmente, o R está interpretando as colunas separadas por espaço como duas colunas e não uma. Tente substituir o padrão 'mês ano' por 'mês_ano'. Vou editar minha resposta para mostrar isso

Comment: Obrigado pela solução!