# Transformar uma Linha em Coluna no R

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho o seguinte dataframe no R
Preciso transformar a linha em uma coluna da seguinte maneira:

```
   Nome  Valor 
1  x     1.1
2  x     2.2
3  y     3.3
4  y     4.4
5  z     5.5
6  z     6.6
```

E preciso que ele fique assim:

```
   x    y    z
1  1.1  3.3  5.5
2  2.2  4.4  6.6
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Como é que esta pergunta é fora de escopo?

Comment: [Duplicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422083/transpor-um-dataframe-no-r), mas não é fora de escopo.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta Não é bem uma duplicada, essa pergunta pede para transpor, [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360773/o-que-s%C3%A3o-dados-no-formato-wide-long) está mais próxima.

Comment: Está certo, @RuiBarradas. De qualquer maneira, não vejo por que foi considerada fora de escopo.

Answer (score 2):

Há várias maneiras de reformatar os dados de formato longo para largo. Vou usar o pacote `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Nome) %>%
  mutate(Grp = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Nome", values_from = "Valor") %>%
  select(-Grp)
## A tibble: 2 x 3
#      x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   1.1   3.3   5.5
#2   2.2   4.4   6.6
```

**Dados.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
   Nome  Valor 
1  x     1.1
2  x     2.2
3  y     3.3
4  y     4.4
5  z     5.5
6  z     6.6
", header = TRUE)
```